# How can I use Motoman stack with ROS Indigo?

Tags: ros, motoman, ros-industrial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191233/how-can-i-use-motoman-stack-with-ros-indigo?/) by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit 2015-04-22: updated as `industrial_core` has been released into Indigo.

---

(I'm assuming no prior ROS experience in this answer .. well, some experience)

While there hasn't been any official release of the `motoman` packages into Indigo, I've had good results building them from source. As far as I know there are no incompatibilities, but you obviously do this **at your own risk**.

You could do something like this (in your current catkin workspace):

```
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src

# checkout the desired version of the motoman repository.
# if you'd rather use the development versions, use '-b hydro-devel' OR '-b indigo-devel'.
git clone -b hydro https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman.git

# we need to make sure you have all dependencies installed.
# this step should install 'industrial_robot_client' for you
cd ..
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo

# now build
catkin_make
```

This should successfully build the Motoman ROS nodes. You'll still have to set up your controller, but those steps are identical to the Hydro version (see [motoman_driver/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials) on the ROS wiki).

To make sure things are ok, try running the tests:

```
catkin_make run_tests
```

then

```
catkin_test_results --all build/
```

The summary should show 0 failures. Especially the tests for `simple_message`, `industrial_robot_client` and all of the `motoman_X_support` packages are important.

Now after a `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, you should be able to start the relevant launch files.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2014-08-31**:
Thanks for your help. I did everything you said and it's OK.
Do you know how can I use this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/motoman/Tutorials/Path_Planning_with_Arm_Warehouse_Viewer

With the instruction
roslaunch sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_sia10d_mesh.launch

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2014-08-31**:
I get
[planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_sia10d_mesh.launch] is neither a launch file in package [sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation] nor is [sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation] a launch file name

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2014-08-31**:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch", line 35, in 
roslaunch.main()
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/**init**.py", line 308, in main
logger.error(traceback.format_exc())

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-31**:
The tutorial you linked is for Fuerte / Groovy. `arm_navigation` is not supported on Hydro / Indigo. So it cannot work. Hydro & Indigo use MoveIt.

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2014-08-31**:
Thank you!